# Remove a numpy array that contains a certain value from a nested numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which is a one dimensional array of one dimensional arrays of zero dimensional arrays. It looks something like this:

`arr = [([([1], [0], [2], [0]]), ([[0], [2], [2]]), ([[0], [1], [2])])]`

I am trying to filter out all zero dimensional arrays that contain value 2, so all [2]s should be removed. The problem is that I need to keep the same overall structure of the array. The result should look like this:

`arr = [([[1], [0], [0]]), ([[0]]), ([0], [1]])]`

I would appreciate any help with this! Also I am wondering if there are good ways to view a .npy files or examine as the original array prints super ugly and I can't figure out a good way to view this file in CLI. Thanks!

I am pretty new to numpy and I can't make it work with general numpy filtering functions like:

`np.where()` or  `arr = arr[cond(arr)]`

Probably because of the nested structure

I tried to use a for loop, but I can't convert the result into the original array

```
mask = (arr[0] != [2])
result = []
for i in arr:
    filtered_arr = arr[0][mask]
    result.append(filtered_arr)

result = np.array(result, dtype=object)`
```

This outputs an array that looks like this:

`[([1, 0, 0]), ([0]), ([0, 1])]`

which is almost what I want, but not entirely.

Comment: How did you initially get/load that `arr` structure?

Comment: I have a provided arr.npy document, and I use np.load(arr.npy, allow_pickle=True)

Comment: can you share a link on that file if it's not confidential?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DXfJ76ynjOCn7RM_zgIIjSjvscN5ID6J/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: `arr` is a list, not a numpy array. Don't try to summarize.

Comment: @SashaGolubeva, the link is not publicly accessible

Comment: If you save a complex list as `npy` it will wrap it in an object dtype array, and pickle it during save.  It's hard to tell from your description how many levels of array versus list you have.  `np.load(file, allow_pickle=True).item()` might be enough to remove that outer numpy layer.

Comment: I apologize for that @RomanPerekhrest. I changed the privacy settings on that file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DXfJ76ynjOCn7RM_zgIIjSjvscN5ID6J/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @SashaGolubeva, your current `arr` acts as a container of numpy arrays of different shape like `[[(534, 1), (426, 1), (502, 1), (602, 1), (190, 1), (458, 1) ....]`. Are you allowed to change the shape of arrays to make them 1-row x many-columns? That will releave you from having vertically lengthy view of arrays, and switch to a more compact wide view

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest! I am wondering how you checked for the sizes and types of data structures in the document? I don't think I can change the general shape because I am feeding my arrays into a model for fitting.  When I tried to change the structure previously, the model did not accept it. I think my problem is that I received very little information on what type of array I was given and what type of array the model takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `arr` is formed as a container/list of *numpy* arrays of different shape like `[[(534, 1), (426, 1), (502, 1), (602, 1), (190, 1), (458, 1) ....]` (check this with `print([a.shape for a in arr])`). Changing the shape of arrays to make them 1-row x many-columns could release you from having vertically lengthy view of arrays, and switch to a more compact wide view. 
But if you're not allowed to change the shape, filter out the rows that have `2` as column value as shown below:

```
arr = np.load(npy_file_path, allow_pickle=True)
# print([a.shape for a in arr])
arr = np.array([a[a[:, 0] != 2] for a in arr], dtype='O')
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much again @RomanPerekhrest!

Answer (score 0):

Dpwnloading the file, and loading with `allow_pickle`, I see an object dtype arrays with 34 elements:

```
In [60]: arr.shape, arr.dtype
Out[60]: ((34,), dtype('O'))
```

It appears that all elements are themselves int dtype arrays, with varying (n,1) shape:

```
In [61]: arr[0].shape, arr[0].dtype
Out[61]: ((534, 1), dtype('int32'))

In [62]: arr[1].shape, arr[1].dtype
Out[62]: ((426, 1), dtype('int32'))
```

In effect it is an list of 2d arrays.

```
In [63]: np.array([i.shape[0] for i in arr])
Out[63]: 
array([534, 426, 502, 602, 190, 458, 360, 470, 500, 645, 537, 484, 472,
       492, 414, 475, 242, 314, 250, 184, 174, 335, 437, 482, 147, 108,
       306, 456, 668, 269, 562, 377, 647, 558])
```

Each array has to be processed individually.  To find all elements of `arr[0]` that don't contain a 2:

```
In [65]: arr[0][arr[0]!=2].shape
Out[65]: (518,)
```

or taking care to mask on the 2nd dim:

```
In [70]: arr[0][arr[0][:,0]!=2].shape
Out[70]: (518, 1)
```

Displaying a (n,1) array like this is awkward, since each number is on a separate line.

The last 20 rows of the unfiltered and filterd array:

```
In [80]: arr[0][-20:,0]
Out[80]: array([0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [81]: arr[0][arr[0][:,0]!=2][-20:,0]
Out[81]: array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

The filtered shapes for a arrays:

```
In [85]: np.array([i[i[:,0]!=2].shape[0] for i in arr])
Out[85]: 
array([518, 375, 407, 523, 137, 407, 323, 380, 452, 493, 470, 355, 379,
       443, 362, 449, 220, 273, 246, 161, 134, 304, 386, 412, 147, 108,
       284, 397, 590, 269, 523, 341, 603, 538])
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, @hpaulj!